# repair ext4 after squashfs thrown error & gparted move failed

Tags: fsck, gparted

i was:

- merging (sda9) unused space with sda10
- moving (sda10) to right to be able to move free space (from merged sda9 to sda14)
  on hdd with gparted gui on ubuntu started from usb and i encounter a crash  and thrown to text mode with multiples "squashfs read metadata / read directory error "

  - i tried to move to console and login but without success/ more squidfs messages
  - i was not been able to reboot/shutdown system via ctrl..del/&more ctl..del or via "short" power button - more squashsf msg

after restart original partition is on its initial place but with errors:

[image]

no i have from fsock:

```
/dev/sda10 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Journal inode is not in use, but contains data.  Clear? no

Inode 133442 has an invalid extent node (blk 536082, lblk 0)
Clear? no

HTREE directory inode 133442 has an invalid root node.
Clear HTree index? no

Inode 133442 is a zero-length directory.  Clear? no

Inode 133442, i_size is 24576, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 133442, i_blocks is 56, should be 0.  Fix? no

HTREE directory inode 138014 has an invalid root node.
Clear HTree index? no

HTREE directory inode 138014 has an unsupported hash version (32)

.
.
.
Illegal block #11269 (2512775914) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Illegal block #11270 (1985700276) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Illegal block #11271 (4072078813) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Illegal block #11272 (2810493027) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Illegal block #11273 (2636815351) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Illegal block #11274 (3127323417) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Too many illegal blocks in inode 261675.
Clear inode? no

Suppress messages? no

Illegal block #11275 (3779719890) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Illegal double indirect block (2515339318) in inode 261675.  IGNORED.
Error while iterating over blocks in inode 261675: Illegal doubly indirect block found

/dev/sda10: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

**how i can restore some data from this partition ? without any external soft**

**ps** i hited yes on first fsock "inode journal clear " ???

**ps2** this was / mountpoint so mostly with irrelevant things - i want only pull some config files form /etc

**btw** which distributions you recommend? after some time with ubuntu i'm testing now arch - i like to use text mode and do most things by myself - realy like to be an admin on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two hopes: restore from backup, or get a spare disk to recover files onto, and try your luck with `photorec`.

Comment: `testdisk` can also repair if most of structure is still here, even with filenames.

Comment: @siblynx, `testdisk` can repair a lost partition table, but it can't deal with a filesystem that has half been moved, and half not.

Comment: Maybe, will not argue. OP's structure is a mess, but fsck output is somewhat still promising. And my experience was to repair ntfs structure which had about a 2% whitespace (overwritten by zeroes) at it's middle.

Comment: @psusi - only about 100 mb were moved - so what option i got?

Comment: btw this is / mountpoint so mostly with irrelevant things - i want only pull some files form /etc